# How bad is it considered to create enums with large enough amount of enumerators and abstract methods

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum RuleItem {
    MORE_THAN(1) {
        @Override
        public String getStringRepresentation() {
            return getRuleStringRepresentation("rulesName.moreThan");
        }
    },
    LESS_THAN(2) {
        @Override
        public String getStringRepresentation() {
            return getRuleStringRepresentation("rulesName.lessThan");
        }
    },
    MORE_OR_EQUAL(3) {
        @Override
        public String getStringRepresentation() {
            return getRuleStringRepresentation("rulesName.moreOrEqual");
        }
    },

    //...

    INTERVAL_WITH_BOUNDS_INCLUDED(27) {
        @Override
        public String getStringRepresentation() {
            return getRuleStringRepresentation("rulesName.intervalWithBounds");
        }
    };
    protected String getRuleStringRepresentation(String resourceName) {
        Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .getLocale();
        String resourceString;
        try {
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME,
                locale);
            resourceString = bundle.getString(resourceName);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return resourceString;
    }

    public abstract String getStringRepresentation();
}
```

I want to add three more abstract methods. Is it considered good the enum contains large amount of public methods? Maybe I should have created just a class in that case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not simply use a constructor, something like:

```
public enum RuleItem {
    MORE_THAN(1, "rulesName.moreThan"),
    LESS_THAN(2, "rulesName.lessThan"),
    MORE_OR_EQUAL(3, "rulesName.moreOrEqual");

    private int value;
    private String representation;

    private RuleItem(int value, String representation) {
        this.value = value;
        this.representation = representation;
    }

    public String getStringRepresentation() {
         return representation;
    }
}
```

You can then add as many arguments and as methods as you'd like, but without having the override it personally for each value (simply pass it in the constructor).

Comment: `representation` in the construtor should be `String` not `int`.

Comment: Oops... Wrote that one too quickly, I guess. Thanks! I've edited my answer  accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem having an enumeration with a number of public methods. Enumeration items are object by themselves.

I like the **Java** `enum` implementation just for this reason: you have objects and not bare values like in C or in C#.

Anyway the enum items should be immutable objects, they could delegate further elaboration to other objects.

```
public interface RuleExecutor {
    public void execute(int param1, int param2);
}
public enum RuleItem {
    MORE_THAN("rulesName.moreThan", new MoreThanExecutor()),
    LESS_THAN("rulesName.lessThan" , new LessThanExecutor()),
    MORE_OR_EQUAL("rulesName.moreOrEqual", new MoreOrEqualExecutor());

    private String representation;
    private RuleExecutor executor;

    private RuleItem(String representation, RuleExecutor executor) {
        this.representation = representation;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public String getStringRepresentation() {
        return getRuleStringRepresentation(representation);
    }

    public void execute(int param1, int param2) {
        this.executor.execute(param1, param2);
    }
}
```